# Pricing a Europen style put option

Tags: finance

So I'm enrolled in a Mathematics for Finance course, and we received this question on the last Problem Set. I'm completely stuck on how to solve this problem. I tried applying the formula xS(t) + yA(t) = C(t), but I get stuck with figuring out A(t) - which represents the price of bonds.

Any help on this would be appreciated. I'm baffled on how to continue with this.

[image]

Comment: Typically, there is an assumption regarding the second moment of the distribution of the underlying asset that is absent here.  This is often given as $u=e^{\sigma \Delta t}$.  Without it, this problem hangs.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: In a one-period market the discount factor is $1/(1+i)$ where $i$ is the risk-free interest rate.  The price of the put option is the discounted expected value of the payoff, $\max(0,K-S(T))$, where the expectation is taken with respect to risk-neutral probabilities $q_u$ and $q_d$.  In the risk-neutral world the expected future stock price is the forward price $S_0(1+i)$. Solve for the risk-neutral probabilities by equating the forward price with this expectation. Then go back and price the option.

Comment: There is one degree of freedom here.  Typically, there is assumption regarding the second moment of the distribution that is absent here.  This is often given as $u=e^{\sigma \Delta t}$.  Without it, this problem hangs.

Comment: Dr. MV: You can use the the spot forward relationship to circumvent that and $q_d = 1 - q_u$ I would simply write the equation but OP should make an attempt.  Or use the hedging argument but that takes more work.

Comment: That is still missing an equation.  You have $u=1/d$, $q_d=1-q_u$, and the arbitrage free condition.  That is three equations with 4 unknowns.  We need one more equation.  As you probably know, with these models, we need to assume a distribution.  Without the second moment, the distribution is not prescribed.

Comment: $S_0(1+i) = q_uuS_0 + (1-q_u)dS_0$.  That means $q_u = [1+i - d]/(u-d)$. Now the probability is determined in terms of known quantities. Now option price is just the discounted expected value using this probability.

Comment: We are not given $u$ or $d$.  So, we are short one equation.  If you are certain that you are correct, please feel free to write the solution.  But I believe that we cannot do this.

Comment: If you are given $u$ -- so you are correct.

Comment: Yes, we need $u$.  And often $u=e^{\sigma \Delta t}$, where $\sigma$ is given.

Comment: But this is the solution in terms of $u$.

Comment: Yes.  If the solution is in terms of $u$, then we you are correct!

Comment: Thanks -- good catch.  I assumed that $u$ was given.  Option can't be priced without knowing the volatility.  Without it the problem is ill-posed and it might have been an error in the problem statement.